# I'm unable to update my document in database using my code, but I'm able to do it in database explicitly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have written a code to send mail when the customers are going to register. Once when they are registered they will get a mail and the code to send mail is as below.

This is my controller

```
module.exports = (function(){
return {
    newRegister: function(request,response){
        var registers = new register(request.body);
        registers.save(function(error,result){
            if(error){
                response.send(error)
                console.log(error)
            }
            else{
                response.json(result)
                var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
                service: "Gmail",
                auth: {
                    user: "some@gmail.com",
                    pass: "*******"
                }
                });

                // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
                var mailOptions = {
                    from: "some@gmail.com", // sender address
                    to: result.email, // list of receivers
                    subject: "Hello", // Subject line
                    //text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
                    html: "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><script type='text/javascript'></script></head><body><p style=font-family:'Times New Roman'>Please click the below link for verification</p><p style=font-family:'Times New Roman'><a href='http://127.0.0.1:3060/email/:id'>Click Here</a></p></body></html>"
                }

                // send mail with defined transport object
                smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                    console.log("Message inside auth: " );

                    if(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }else{
                        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                    }

                    // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore, uncomment following line
                    //smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
                    });
            }
        })
    }
 }
})();
```

This is the update method I have written to update when the link is clicked.

```
changeStatus: function(request, response){
      register.findOneAndUpdate({"email": request.params.id}, {$set: {"status": true}}, {returnNewDocument: true}, function(error,result){
          if(error){
              response.send(error)
              console.log(error)
          }
          else{
              response.json(result)
              console.log(result)
          }
      })

    }
```

And this my route

```
app.get('/email/:id', function(request,response){
registercontroller.changeStatus(request,response)
response.send("User activated")
})
```

when the link is clicked I'm getting the output as

```
User activated
null
```

I'm not able to find where I went wrong.

Comment: In your route app.get you call registercontroller.changeStatus and inside that function you call either response.send or json but you also call response.send from the route, I'm pretty sure you should get an error saying something like *"Cannot send headers, already sent"* you can't call response.send twice, it will always result in an error.

Comment: Molda, I have removed response.send() from route, still I'm getting null as output

Comment: And where is that null coming from? I mean is it on server or client and what do you expect it to be? Also what is the output from console.log(result); in register.findOneAndUpdate?

Comment: Null is coming from the "changeStatus" function, that means it should return updated document instead it is returning null on clientside. I'm expecting the output to be updated document from mongodb(only the status field should be updated and remaining fields should be unchanged). The output of console.log(result) is also "null".

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like below:-

```
changeStatus: function(request, response)
 {
  register.findOneAndUpdate({"email": request.params.id},
                            {$set: {"status": true}}, 
                             {new: true},//Made changes here. 
  function(error,result)
  {
      if(error)
       {
          response.send(error)
          console.log(error)
      }
      else
      {
          response.json(result)
          console.log(result)
      }
  })
}
```

Use `new : true` in the query, to get the modified record. See [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) for more info on how to use.

Hope this will help.

Comment: can you try doing find for  `({"email": request.params.id})` query and tell is there any result or not?

Comment: So there is no such record, what you are trying to update, in your db. How you are expecting result will come? There is something wrong with your find query itself. Please check it and then try again.